# Why does Stack Overflow use pagination above the answer list?

Tags: discussion, design

You can see pagination on the top and the bottom of the answers in the question page of those questions which have lots of answers. Bottom side pagination looks good for me, but why use the same pagination at the top side? Because I always got confused; usually I'm thinking the top pagination is for that specific answer (only) and may be there is more detail of this particular answer if I go to next page. But as you know this is pagination for all answers. I just wanted to know, how is this supposed to be user friendly? Or what are the benefits?

[Sample Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery) with lots of answers.

Comment: It's conceivable that one would want to jump to a page without first reading through all the answers on the current page, no? There could maybe be a moment's confusion to a newbie as to what the pagination menu refers to, and that could be solved by adding another line underneath it, but it's obvious to anyone who knows the system and it's not a huge UI problem either way

Answer (score 3):

The benefit is that you can easily go to the 'worst' answer (if 'voting' is your sorting option) or newest answer (if 'oldest' is your sorting option). You don't need to scroll all the way down then.

> usually i'm thinking the top pagination is for that specific answer (only)

IMHO, you're the only one. An answer is a *single* entity; pagination always applies to *lists* of entities. We don't have a 'read more' option for answers here; they are always shown in full.

If it keeps bothering you, you can install a custom stylesheet hiding the element:

```
#answers-header + .pager-answers {
    display: none;
}
```

The `#answers-header +` is there to prevent the bottom pager from disappearing.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to turn off pagination, via a query string parameter, perhaps?

Comment: @Jonah sorry, no.